# Deserialize json string to string object in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json string coming from api.

Sometimes I receive the `address` as an object and sometimes as a simple string. Two examples:

case 1. (Here the `address` is an object.)

```
"{\"name\":\"vikram\",\"address\":{\"city\":\"hisar\"}}";
```

case 2. (Here the `address` is a simple string.)

```
"{\"name\":\"vikram\",\"address\":\"North india\"}";
```

I am trying to deserialize this json to a `Data` object.
Here is the code for class `Data`

```
public class Data{
    String name;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = StringDeserializer.class)
    String address;

    public Data(){}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                    '}';
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

I am able to deserialize second case successfully, but not the first one because, in first instance, `address` is an json object. It is throwing the following exception.

> Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token

Is there any way to map json object to string using jackson `ObjectMapper`?

I know that I can use `Object` reference instead of `String` in `Data` class but I want it to be a string.

I tried added `@JsonDeserialize(using = StringDeserializer.class)` but that did not work.

Comment: Can you first test the json string if the address field is a plain string or not, then decide into which kind of `Data` object to deserialize?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some annotation trickery that does the trick, but I think you should just bite the bullet and write your own `JsonDeserializer`.

Here's a quick-and-dirty example to get you started:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;

public class Data {

    @JsonProperty
    String name;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = AddressDeserializer.class)
    String address;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", address='" + address + '\'' + '}';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().readValue("{\"name\":\"vikram\",\"address\":{\"city\":\"hisar\"}}", Data.class));
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().readValue("{\"name\":\"vikram\",\"address\":\"North india\"}", Data.class));
    }

}

class AddressDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    private static final TypeReference<Map<String,Object>> MAP_STRING_OBJECT = new TypeReference<>(){ /* empty */ };

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        if (p.currentToken().isStructStart()) {
            Map<String,Object> map = p.readValueAs(MAP_STRING_OBJECT);
            return map.get("city").toString();
        } else {
            return p.readValueAs(String.class);
        }
    }

}
```